# How to access a textbox from a .cpp file?

Tags: .net, windows, winforms, c++-cli

**How can I access a Text Box that is in `Form1.h` (on the Windows Form) from a `.cpp` file?**

I would like that when a user presses a button on a form, some text is added to a textbox on the same form. When the button is pressed I'd like to call a class in the `.cpp` file that would (after some calculations and whatnot) add some text to the textbox.

I've been trying to figure this out for a while, but to no avail.

Would anybody like to share how I could do this?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the cpp file is for Form1, `#include "Form1.h"`, then `this->textBox`.

if the cpp file is for another class, you'll need to pass a reference to either the Form1 object or the TextBox. Probably pass this in the class's constructor is the easiest way to do it. If you decide to pass the Form1 object, do the same #include. If you decide to just pass the TextBox, just don't forget to do the `using namespace`.